# Dolbeault complex of a holomorphic bundle.

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I have a question that seems stupid to me, but I don't understand why it doesn't work, it's about the Dolbeault operator. Let $E$ be a holomorphic vector bundle, and let $\Omega_X^{p,q}$ be the bundle of holomorphic forms of type $(p,q)$ on $X$. I recale that, if $(U_i,\theta_i)$ is a cover of trivialisation of $E$, then the sections of $\Omega_X^{p,q}\otimes E$ on $U_i$ is isomorphic to the space $\Omega_X^{p,q}(U_i)^n.$ And we have for a globale section $\alpha$ we associate the familly $((\alpha_1^i,\dots,\alpha_n^i))_i$ correspond to $(\alpha_{/U_i})_i$ and on $U_{ij}$ we have :
$$(\alpha_1^i,\dots,\alpha_n^i)= g_{i,j} (\alpha_1^j,\dots,\alpha_n^j),       (*)$$
where $g_{i,j}$ are the cocycle associated to the trivialisation, which is holomorphic. A such familly give arise to a global section.

We define $(\partial_E \alpha)$ as the section of associated the the familly $((\bar{\partial}\alpha_1^i,\dots, \bar{\partial}\alpha_n^i))_i$.

Now I want to prove that:

$$\bar{\partial}_E(\alpha\wedge\beta)= \bar{\partial}_E(\alpha)\wedge\beta+(-1)^{p+q}\alpha\wedge \bar{\partial}\beta.$$

First, if I understand correctly, the section $\alpha \wedge \beta$, corresponds to $(\alpha_1^i\wedge \beta_1^i,\dots,\alpha_1^i \wedge \beta_1^i)$ on the open set $U_i$. My question is:

Do the familly  $((\alpha_1^i\wedge \beta_1^i,\dots,\alpha_1^i \wedge \beta_1^i))_i$ verifie the condition of cocycle $(*)$ to be good defined in the sens of the first paragraphe ? I don’t think..

The second one: If I assume that my definition for the exterior product is correct, then it is immediat that we have
$$\bar{\partial}(f\alpha)=df\wedge \alpha +f. \bar{\partial}(\alpha),(**)$$

I hope you have an answer if my previous definition is wrong.

Comment: First of all, $(p,q)$-forms can be holomorphic only when $q=0$. So I’m not sure much of this makes sense.  Since $E$ and only $E$ here is holomorphic, the $\bar\partial$ operator maps holomorphic sections of $E$ to $E$-valued holomorphic $1$-forms.

Comment: I think Dolbeault operator is well defined for any $(p,q)$. You means that $\alpha \wedge \beta$ is not well defined? I didn’t get your remark.

Comment: Of course the Dolbeault operator is well-defined. But it maps *smooth* $(p,q)$-forms with values in $E$ to *smooth* $(p,q+1]$-forms with values in $E$. The wedge product is problematic becase we don’t in general have a map $E\otimes E\to E$.

Comment: So, I don't really understand how this wedge product is defined, because in Voisin’s book it's nowhere defined, and she mention the Leibniz rule as a « evident proposition ». and I felt it should be like that, and that's clearly not well defined.

Comment: Leibniz is fine when wedge product is defined, but it’s not for general vector bundles. The way we usually think about $\bar\partial_E$ is a sort of Leibniz: Define $\bar\partial_E (\omega\otimes s) = \bar\partial \omega\otimes s \pm \omega\wedge\bar\partial_E s$.